# How to run Sinatra in background and then access it later on

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sinatra, cucumber, multiprocessing

I am looking to start sinatra in the background, then stop/reload it during my tests... So far my reading has provided 2 solutions to run sinatra in the background, either by forking the process or starting it in a new Thread... what I couldn't figure out is how I can stop/reload the Sinatra service within that child process (when forked) or thread

Some code of what I am doing to run it in the background:

```
Thread.start do
  SinatraApp.run!
end
```

or

```
fork do
    SinatraApp.run!
end
```

What I want to do is after starting sinatra, be able to set which would trigger sinatra/reload

```
SinatraApp.set params
```

but that won't do anything because Sinatra is running in a different thread/process

any thoughts?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I prefer webmock for testing. If Sinatra is running the app under test, maybe you can start it in the before hooks and have special tagged hooks to run it in special configurations.

Comment: I am using sinatra because I need to stub a page(html) and prior to starting the stub I need to inject data into the html and Sinatra erb views makes it pretty convenient... Plus running in hooks still would require me to run it in the background and hence I still would need a way to access the child process/thread to stop/reload it

Comment: Then I would recommend using WebMock. I've used it for rest services, but it can be used for web pages. I use it with cucumber. I can create a stub that returns whatever I want in a Given step definition, call the web page in a When step definition, and verify my application processed the data received correctly in a Then step definition.

Comment: hmmmmm I am taking a look at the documentation... I will give it a try! thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: i am trying to do this in order to test my app with cucumber. i need more control over the startup than things like `Capybara.app = MyApp` will give me